# Row spanning in crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I want to create a crystal report in the below format which row spanning .

Customer No
Account No
Trans Amount
Date

```
100 

       10000

           100.00      02/05/2011 

           200.00      02/05/2011 
       20000           

           300.00      02/05/2011
```

Means 100 is same and it should not get repeated in all rows, similarly 10000 is same for below 2 rows so it should not be repeated.
Is it possible to achieve the above formatting in crystal reports.. if yes then how to do it..any sample example will help. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use groups within crystal.  Create a group on Customer No and then Account No.  Then put the Trans Amount and Date in the detail field.

If you need more information, try [this page](http://www.ehow.com/how_6530417_use-grouping-crystal-reports.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use the Group Expert to create a group first on `Customer No` and secondly on `Account No`. Remove both `Customer No` and `Account No` from the `Details` section of the report and place them correspondingly into their new group header sections.

Normally a newly created group will show only the group name (like "Cusomer No"). Please the actual report fields into their group headers.